# How to catch a FacesFileNotFoundException?

Tags: exception, jsf, jakarta-ee, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

How can I catch a

> com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException

in a Java EE web application?

I tried it with adding the following lines in my web.xml file but I was not successful:

```
  ...
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>FacesFileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/404.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/404.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>FailingHttpStatusCodeException</exception-type>
    <location>/404.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the FQN (Full Qualified Name), not just the N as exception type.

```
<exception-type>com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException</exception-type>
```

Alternatively, if you already happen to use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), register its [`FacesExceptionFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter) and then the `FacesFileNotFoundException` will be handled as 404.

Comment: What exactly happens instead?

Comment: The output is the following: 1. StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException 2. PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception 3. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@16933312: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException, location=/404.jsf]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Context is already active at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:422)

Comment: Make it a plain JSP/HTML page instead and retry.

Comment: THIS WORKS!!! I think it is because I want to use a JSF for a JSF exception which is not possible because JSF already crashed (due to the exception)!? THANK YOU!